# Is it possible to create a patch using a set of changelists?

Tags: perforce

Problem: 2 projects shared trunk and were updating some of the same files. Now one project needs to be released, so a new branch was created from a checkpoint before the projects started.

I have a list of just my changelist numbers from the mainline. Using that I can generate a list changed files and diff output using a script with a series of 'p4 describe #' commands.

Can I reformat that output and apply it to the new branch somehow?

Answer (score 25):

Response to the title: "Is it possible to create a patch using a set of changelists?"
Yes.

```
p4 diff2 -u //path_to_your_sources/...@cln_minus_1 //path_to_your_sources/...@cln > /tmp/cln.patch.
```

You can then use /tmp/cln.patch as input to the patch utility. Here, 'cln' is the submitted change list number that you want to create a patch for.

Comment: Note that `p4 diff2` will not output diffs for added or deleted files, so those would need special handling to get `patch` to add or delete them.

Comment: @jamesdlin like what, for example?

Comment: @DanM. You'd have to manually diff added or deleted files against empty files.  More specifically, for an added file, you'd have to manually run `diff -u EMPTY_FILE ADDED_FILE`.  For a deleted file, you'd have to get the prior revision of the file and do `diff -u OLD_FILE EMPTY_FILE`.

Comment: @DanM. Additionally, to be proper, the empty file should be have a timestamp of 0 (1970-01-01T00:00:00Z) (or use `diff -N` with non-existent files instead of empty ones).  See "You can create a file by..." paragraph [from the `patch` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/patch.1.html) for details.

Comment: @jamesdlinso no easy way to automate this?

Answer (score 9):

I've just spent two hours struggling with this. Using cygwin `patch`, I had to munge the paths until they were recognised.

In the end, the magic incantation looked like this (broken across lines):

```
p4 diff2 -u //depot/foo/main/...@100003 //depot/foo/main/...@100000 |
    sed 's@//depot/@E:/Source/@g' |
    sed '/^+++\|---/s@/@\\@g' |
    patch
```

That is:

1. Use `p4 diff2` to get a unified diff (`-u`) of part of the depot between the two revisions that I care about. The second changelist is the one *before* the first one I want, otherwise it's not included in the diff.
2. Use `sed` to change the `//depot/` to `E:/Source/`, which is where my workspace lives.
3. Change forward slashes to double backslashes (this seems to make it work).
4. Pipe the results through `patch`.

Cygwin `patch` is smart enough to check files out of Perforce, but I'm not sure how to get it to do it silently. It prompts with `Get file 'e:\Source\foo\whatever' from Perforce with lock?`.

This is with `p4` version 2010.1, a fairly recent installation of Cygwin, running on PowerShell.

Oh, and after this, `patch` wrote out Unix-style line endings, so I used `u2d` to fix those up.

Comment: See my comment to http://stackoverflow.com/a/4925343/179715 for a caveat about using `p4 diff2`.

Answer (score 5):

Perforce will let you cherry-pick changelists for integration, which may be easier than trying to generate and apply a patch. Perforce will keep track of what revisions you've integrated where, which may make future integrations easier.

Let's assume you used to have one trunk:

```
//depot/mycode/trunk
```

And you checked in all of your changes there. You branched trunk at some point in the past to:

```
//depot/mycode/rel
```

And you have a list of changelists on trunk to merge. From a client spec that maps rel, integrate each changelist:

```
p4 integrate //depot/mycode/trunk/...@1234,1234 //depot/mycode/rel/...
```

where `1234` is the changelist number. Resolve after each integration. You may also wish to build, test, and commit your integrations at various checkpoints during your integration, if you can identify good points to do so. (Perforce can handle multiple integrations per commit, but if you make a mistake you'll need to revert to the last version checked in and redo the intermediate integrations and resolves.)

Comment: Why do I need to resolve if I'm going to be the only one checking in? 

Doesn't integrating the changelist only factor in code that was modified for that commit? I can picture conflicts if it was looking at the whole file.

Comment: Perforce makes you resolve every time you integrate in case you need to address, by hand, any conflicts. In your case, you'd get conflicts if your new changelist altered code added in a previous changelist.

Answer (score -2):

`p4 describe -S -du <CL number>`

is the shorter and most concise command, in my opinion.